# Images on a TabControl show at design time but not at runtime (VB.NET)

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

In a VB.NET winform App I want to place icons on each tab header of a TabControl.

I set the ImageList property of the TabControl and for each Tab I set the ImageKey property.
My icons show as expected on each tab at design time within the IDE but when I run the App, my icons don't show (an empty space is shown instead).

I can't seem to find what's going wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Undiagnosable from the question.  Post a small repro project to a file sharing service.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the visible property? I know of one bug that Microsoft never fixed on the TabControl that makes ToolStrips disappear from time to time. It sets the visible property to false at some point.